# Can Byte Buddy generalize usage of the @Super annotation so that it could be used to intercept any function?

Tags: java, minecraft, byte-buddy

My subclass has a property which is an instance of its parent class. I wanted to intercept most of the functions in this subclass using interceptors, so that way it would call the same function on the parent class with the args passed. However, I have two issues: I don't know how to access the property, and call the function by unpacking the args at the same time.

I'm trying to create a subclass for a class in Minecraft that I'm already injecting into using Mixins, which does the thing I said above. The only problem is that that class has over 100 functions, and I'm not sure which ones I need to override in order to get the functionality I need.  I was curious if Byte Buddy was suitable for this task, or if I need to consider a different solution entirely.

Comment: 1) What do you mean with “parent class”? superclass, perhaps? 2) What do you mean with “functions”? methods, perhaps? 3) How is Bytebuddy supposed to help you when you don’t know what you have to do (which methods you need to override)? Magic, perhaps?

Comment: My goal was to override all the public methods to see if doing such a thing was going to work. Using Java's Reflection library, I can get a list of these methods easily enough, so the hard part is just using Byte Buddy to apply the interceptor to each one generally without knowing the arguments/return types beforehand. Byte buddy can do this but I just had no idea how to access the state of the parent object at the same time, or if that's even possible.

Comment: What do you mean with “parent object”?

Comment: I mean the object I am intercepting, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I do not quite follow either. Could you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, basically what I'm trying to do is make an object which basically acts as a "firewall" or "filter" for another object, as it routes all methods with the same input args to the same method on another one, and then has special checks for a few specific methods so that specific behavior is achieved.